# Dropbox reconnect on network connection established

Tags: 10.04, networking

I am running UNR (but using the regular gnome launcher) and have DropBox installed. Since I use my laptop on the train, there is no network connectivity. However once I reconnect to a network, dropbox seems to be completely unresponsive to the fact that there is a network connection and has to be restarted (which means lots of hard drive scanning, battery usage, slowdowns, etc). Is there a way to get dropbox to reconnect automatically, or gota wait for a patch?

**Edit**:

Nothing special about my network configuration, pretty much out-of-the-box. Note that most of the time I connect to wifi not cable. But the problem does not change in either case.

And I forgot to mention, I usually put my computer to sleep/hibernate in between leaving home and using it on the train so it "loses" or "gains" connection on waking up.

**More Edit**:

I just had the problem happening again. Basically it has a network cable plugged in. Goes to sleep. On wakeup (cable still plugged in) dropbox is stuck at "connecting".

Comment: I run Dropbox on my Ubuntu/Gnome Desktop (10.04), and I've had quite a few local LAN outages lately. Dropbox has recovered on it's own every time. Perhaps this isn't a dropbox-specific problem?

Comment: Hm, I never seemed to have a problem with that. For me, Dropbox always recognizes when the connection goes up and syncs automatically. Of course, I've been working on Gentoo, I don't know if that makes the difference somehow...

Comment: It could be something with your Network Manager configuration - are you using a not standard network "adapter" name (other than eth0)?

Comment: I've had to restart it every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to lack of response I am going to assume that this is a problem with Dropbox itself and not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Does it still happen if you just disconnect your network cable then reconnect without suspending?  If not, you may have a timing problem like the dropbox process already being suspended when the network goes down.  You could try putting a script into `/etc/pm/sleep.d` that explicitly takes down the network interface before suspending, maybe with a short sleep to give dropbox time to process the event.

If worse comes to worst you could always put a script in there to restart dropbox.  At least then you wouldn't have to do it manually every time.

Comment: I can't just restart dropbox. It starts indexing files and thus eats up the little performance the laptop has.

However, unplugging and re-plugging the network cable works, I wait for dropbox to lose connection and then re-plug. As a side note, Skype seems to have no problem reconnecting in all cases. What would you recommend for sleep.d?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu One, for the record, does not suffer from this issue and disconnects/reconnects depending on the network status autimatically.